# Swagger - hide api version parameters

Tags: c#, .net, api, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

Is it possible to hide the 'api-version' and 'x-api-version' parameters?

```
        services.AddApiVersioning(config =>
        {
            config.ReportApiVersions = true;
            config.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
            config.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;

            config.ApiVersionReader = ApiVersionReader.Combine(
             new QueryStringApiVersionReader(),
             new HeaderApiVersionReader()
             {
                 HeaderNames = { "x-api-version" }
             });
        });

        services.AddVersionedApiExplorer(
            options =>
            {
                // note: the specified format code will format the version as "'v'major[.minor][-status]"
                options.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";

                options.DefaultApiVersionParameterDescription = "Do NOT modify api-version!";
            });
```

I already checked [how-to-set-up-swashbuckle-vs-microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40929916/how-to-set-up-swashbuckle-vs-microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-versioning) which implements a 'RemoveVersionFromParameter' method, but in that case the Swagger page would loose the api version and always uses the default v1.0. As shown in the code snippet, I am using the QueryStringApiVersionReader and  HeaderApiVersionReader, but I don't want to support the url api versioning.

Note: The API does have multiple swagger json pages for all versions (e.g. V1, V1.1, V2.0)

[image]

Answer (score 14):

You can try an operation filter. This is similar to Helder's solution, but the implementation doesn't have to be at the document level, so it seems simpler:

```cs
public void Configure(SwaggerGenOptions options)
{
    // Filter out `api-version` parameters globally
    options.OperationFilter<ApiVersionFilter>();
}

internal class ApiVersionFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        var parametersToRemove = operation.Parameters.Where(x => x.Name == "api-version").ToList();
        foreach (var parameter in parametersToRemove)
            operation.Parameters.Remove(parameter);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works. A simpler solution may be just to look for the parameter object, i.e, "parameterToRemove = operation.Parameters.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "api-version");" and then remove it from the list of parameters ("operation.Parameters.Remove(parameterToRemove)"). There's no need of a foreach.

Comment: Nice and clean solution

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into `IDocumentFilter` with that you can remove stuff from the final swagger.json and that will remove it from the UI

Here is an example me removing some properties from the definitions:

```
    private class HideStuffDocumentFilter : IDocumentFilter
    {
        public void Apply(SwaggerDocument swaggerDoc, SchemaRegistry s, IApiExplorer a)
        {
            foreach (var definition in swaggerDoc.definitions)
            {
                foreach (var prop in definition.Value.properties.ToList())
                {
                    if (prop.Value.maxLength == 9999)
                        definition.Value.properties.Remove(prop);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have a few more samples here:
https://github.com/heldersepu/Swagger-Net-Test/blob/e701b1d20d0b42c1287c3da2641ca521a0a7b592/Swagger_Test/App_Start/SwaggerConfig.cs#L766

Answer (score 2):

Do you *really* want to hide the API version parameters or just make them read-only? The API version parameter is required when invoking the API so that *should* not be hidden from the documentation or user.

Your question implies that you're more concerned that the user not be able to change the API version default value for a particular documented API. That's fair, but has a different solution.

While you can mark a parameter as read-only, I have not been able to get the UI to honor that. It might be a bug or something else is misconfigured. You can definitely get read-only like behavior by using an enumeration with a single value. For example:

```cs
public class SwaggerDefaultValues : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply( OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context )
    {
        var apiDescription = context.ApiDescription;

        operation.Deprecated |= apiDescription.IsDeprecated();

        if ( operation.Parameters == null )
        {
            return;
        }

        foreach ( var parameter in operation.Parameters )
        {
            var description = apiDescription.ParameterDescriptions
                                            .First( p => p.Name == parameter.Name );

            parameter.Description ??= description.ModelMetadata?.Description;

            if ( parameter.Schema.Default == null &&
                 description.DefaultValue != null &&
                 description.DefaultValue is not DBNull &&
                 description.ModelMetadata is ModelMetadata modelMetadata )
            {
                var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(
                    description.DefaultValue,
                    modelMetadata.ModelType );

                // this will set the API version, while also making it read-only
                parameter.Schema.Enum = new[] { OpenApiAnyFactory.CreateFromJson( json ) };
            }

            parameter.Required |= description.IsRequired;
        }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can [add your own custom CSS](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#inject-custom-css)
and use it to hide those elements (and do any other customisation you want).

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    ...
    c.InjectStylesheet("/swagger-ui/custom.css");
    ...
});
```

---

**Edit** - example:

Suppose you're trying to hide - in my example; you can easily adapt it to yours - the `tenantId` parameter in this "Remove Basket" operation:

[image]

This would do that:

```
div#operations-baskets-remove tr[data-param-name="tenantId"] {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain how I can hide those parameters, because in the html the parameters don't have an Id, e.g.: <tr data-param-name="api-version" data-param-in="query"> ?

Comment: @Odrai - there are plenty of IDs; you don't need an ID on the exact element you're trying to hide.  Use the "C" part of CSS, go up to find a useful ID, then cascade down to the element you want.  I've added an example to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by setting ApiExplorerOption **SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true** . In your case:

```
    services.AddVersionedApiExplorer(
        options =>
        {
            // note: the specified format code will format the version as "'v'major[.minor][-status]"
            options.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";

            options.DefaultApiVersionParameterDescription = "Do NOT modify api-version!";
            options.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
        });
```

Comment: Your suggestion **only** works if you version by URL segment. The question clearly states they are not versioning that way and don't want to.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me.

```
public class SwaggerOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (operation?.Parameters == null
            || !operation.Parameters.Any())
        {
            return;
        }

        var parametersWithPropertiesToIgnore = context.ApiDescription
            .ActionDescriptor.Parameters.Where(p =>
                p.ParameterType.GetProperties()
                    .Any(t => t.GetCustomAttribute<IgnoreDataMemberAttribute>() != null));

        foreach (var parameter in parametersWithPropertiesToIgnore)
        {
            var ignoreDataMemberProperties = parameter.ParameterType.GetProperties()
                .Where(t => t.GetCustomAttribute<IgnoreDataMemberAttribute>() != null)
                .Select(p => p.Name);

            operation.Parameters = operation.Parameters.Where(p => !ignoreDataMemberProperties.Contains(p.Name))
                .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

On Startup

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Api", Version = "v1" });
            c.SchemaFilter<SwaggerSchemaFilter>();
            c.OperationFilter<SwaggerOperationFilter>();

            var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
            var filePath = Path.Combine(System.AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
            c.IncludeXmlComments(filePath);
        });
```

Just add the data annotation [IgnoreDataMember] in the property to hide it.

```
public class ExampleRequest
{

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public string? HiddenProp { get; set; }

    public string OtherProp { get; set; }
}
```

I have based on [this article](https://dev.to/kenakamu/c-aspnet-hide-model-properties-from-swagger-doc-626) to create this solution.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can added startup.cs file.

```
services.AddApiVersioning(options =>
        {
            // reporting api versions will return the headers "api-supported-versions" and "api-deprecated-versions"
            options.ReportApiVersions = true;
        });


services.AddVersionedApiExplorer(options =>
        {
            // add the versioned api explorer, which also adds IApiVersionDescriptionProvider service
            // note: the specified format code will format the version as "'v'major[.minor][-status]"
            options.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";

            // note: this option is only necessary when versioning by url segment. the SubstitutionFormat
            // can also be used to control the format of the API version in route templates
            options.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
        });
```

And then,you can added top on the controller. But I try to without this([ApiVersion("1.0")]),it could run.I had successfully hide version parametre.

```
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/Check")]
[ApiController]
[Authorize]
public class CheckController : ControllerBase {}
```